# How do I solve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException on Heroku?

Tags: java, ssl, heroku, jvm, keytool

I faced `SSLHandshakeException` on Heroku.

This app was not SSL app. But this app called a ssl-based web api from inside of the app.
Usually, using keytool to adopt SSL cert to JVM solves this kind of problem.

But how do I this on Heroku?

logs here:

```
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:  PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:  unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:324) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:235) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:147) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:270) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:197) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:255) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:319) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:235) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:147) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    2012-06-12T11:08:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:224) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are making a `SSL connection to a server, you should be having the Server's certificate` in the client truststore.

You should `import the server certificate into a keystore` and specify the keystore using `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`.

Check if you have specified these properties. If already specified check if they point to keystore properly.

Comment: Thank you.
I will try.

And I found that this ssl cert was actually self-certified after post this question.
I solved this problem by asking the admin to change the cert to the appropriate one.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that this is only necessary if the server certificate is self-signed. If it is signed by a recognized Certificate Authority you don't have to do anything.

Comment: The original question was specific to Heroku and I would still like to know how to import a (self-signed) certificate into the JVM keystore when I don't have access to the actual JVM on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am not sure if heroku has any support to update keystore but you can always provide your own keystore as java environment parameters in your config or procfile like this

```
web: java -jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit --port $PORT target/*.war
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix SSL certificate validation issue (usually happens with self signed certificates) you need to add certificate to java keystore to tell JVM always trust it.

To add it locally:

- find your keystore file (usually located in *jre/lib/security/cacerts*)
- download certificate .cer file ([here are few ways to do that](https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file), I think downloading with Firefox is the easiest one)
- Import certificate to your keystore: `keytool -import -keystore cacerts -file custom.cer`

Upload your keystore to Heroku by [adding *cacerts* file as a custom JVM file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/customizing-the-jdk#add-custom-files).

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the process in the [blog](https://deepaksinghviblog.blogspot.com/2021/04/heroku-custom-trust-store-for-ssl.html) using which I could succesfully customize the cacerts in Heroku.

https://deepaksinghviblog.blogspot.com/2021/04/heroku-custom-trust-store-for-ssl.html